# WPF Resources.ContextMenu.MenuItem binding to ContextMenu.PlacementTarget.(AttachedProperty)

Tags: wpf, binding, contextmenu, menuitem, resourcedictionary

if the title didn't scare you away, here goes...

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- so the attached CustomObject can bind to the context -->
    <my:BindingProxy x:Key="DataContextProxy" Data="{Binding}" />

    <!-- for chaining IsNull to Visibility.Collapsed -->
    <my:ConverterGroup x:Key="IsNullToVisibility">
        <my:IsNullConverter />
        <my:VisibilityValuesEqual />
    </my:ConverterGroup>

    <ContextMenu x:Key="ctxmnu">
        <MenuItem Header="Copy"   Click="ctxmnu_itmCopy_Click" />
        <MenuItem Header="Add"    Click="ctxmnu_itmAdd_Click"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding  Source={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu},
                                       Path=PlacementTarget,
                                       Converter={StaticResource IsNotNullConverter}}"
                  Visibility="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu},
                                       Path=PlacementTarget.(myAP:APClass.Property),
                                       Converter={StaticResource IsNullToVisibility}}"
                  />
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.Resources>


    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Description}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource ctxmnu}">
        <myAP:APClass.Property>
            <myAP:CustomObject ID="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}, Path=ID}" />
        </myAP:APClass.Property>
    </Label>

</UserControl>
```

Basically, I've got a context menu, with two menu items... the first (copy) is always available... the second (Add) is only available if the context menu is applied from a UIElement with the attached property.

Most of this works... attached property is correctly binding via the proxy resource, menuitem click event is able to get the attached property value.

The only thing that DOESN'T work is the MenuItem.IsEnabled/Visibility binding (I was initially going to bind visibility, but lately I'm thinking IsEnabled is a better idea for UX).

The error is in the binding. Standard error 40 in the output window.

```
System.Windows.Data
 Error: 40 :
 BindingExpression path error:
 'PlacementTarget' property not found on 'object' ''RelativeSource' (HashCode=22838427)'.
 BindingExpression:Path=PlacementTarget.(0); DataItem='RelativeSource' (HashCode=22838427);
 target element is 'MenuItem' (Name='');
 target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
```

Thing is, every article or example I've been able to find (regarding MenuItem binding to PlacementTarget) has the context menu directly on the UIElement, and since the binding occurs when the window/control is instantiated (before the context menu is shown), I'm thinking that the PlacementTarget is NULL and thus error.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using the `Source` property of the binding to assign a `RelativeSource`. It should be:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you look at the error it actually explains it:

```
'PlacementTarget' property not found on 'object' ''RelativeSource'
```

The object should've been the context menu.

Comment: need to adjust my code a tad (right now the condition results are backwards)... but I don't see errors, and the different uses of context menu are showing differences in the result... pretty sure this got it!... will award once confirmed

Comment: yep, you got it... bounty will be awarded as soon as I can... I thought Source was an abstraction and that RelativeSource was the implementation... clearly not the case... thx again!